# How can i fix this kernel error in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, android, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-irkernel, pydroid

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1704, in _execute
    result = await result
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 769, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/handlers.py", line 69, in post
    model = yield maybe_future(
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 762, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 769, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 98, in create_session
    kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 762, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 769, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 110, in start_kernel_for_session
    kernel_id = yield maybe_future(
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 762, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/notebook/services/kernels/kernelmanager.py", line 176, in start_kernel
    kernel_id = await maybe_future(self.pinned_superclass.start_kernel(self, **kwargs))
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_client/multikernelmanager.py", line 186, in start_kernel
    km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_client/manager.py", line 337, in start_kernel
    kernel_cmd, kw = self.pre_start_kernel(**kw)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_client/manager.py", line 286, in pre_start_kernel
    self.write_connection_file()
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_client/connect.py", line 466, in write_connection_file
    self.connection_file, cfg = write_connection_file(self.connection_file,
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_client/connect.py", line 136, in write_connection_file
    with secure_write(fname) as f:
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 113, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_core/paths.py", line 471, in secure_write
    raise RuntimeError("Permissions assignment failed for secure file: '{file}'."
RuntimeError: Permissions assignment failed for secure file: '/storage/emulated/0/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/kernel-fd68a9c5-03c0-405c-9cdd-b85b59fd7acc.json'. Got '0o660' instead of '0o0600'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried update these modules jupyter_client and jupyter_core